# How to convert e.g. CodePage 1250 (Windows-1250) to Unicode using Lazarus

Tags: unicode, lazarus, codepages

**Objective:**

Using Lazarus create a function for conversion strings from CodePage 1250 (Windows-1250) into Unicode.

Comment: Show your work please.

Comment: @AdamMartin see the answer

Comment: What version of FreePascal/Lazarus are you using? The latest version now supports [codepage-aware strings](http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_New_Features_3.0#Support_for_codepage-aware_strings). You can define an `AnsiString` that has codepage 1250 associated with it, and then just assign it as-is to a `UnicodeString`, and the compiler/RTL will perform a proper Unicode conversion at runtime for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Lazarus 1.6 / FreePascal 3.0. I switched from 1.4 version after your comment. As there is not the latest version in the repository, I downloaded the package manually, though I don't like to do this.

Comment: @burian.vlastimil: I don't know which repository you are referring to, as the main FreePascal and Lazarus repositories on SourceForge do have 3.0.0 and 1.6, respectively.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry, I forget to tell you I am on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found only one way to do this effectively, feel free to add your own research.

```
uses
  LConvEncoding;
```

...

```
function ConvertStrFromCP1250ToUnicode(TextAsCP1250: string): unicodestring;

var
  TextAsUTF8: string;

begin

  TextAsUTF8 := CP1250ToUTF8(TextAsCP1250);

  Result := TextAsUTF8;

end;
```